# SQL get min while ignoring default date if other entries for the same id exist

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate

I want to get the `min` of the given dates, grouped by the ID.

If there are multiple entries for an `ID`, I want to *ignore* the default date (`00/00/0000`) - if there's any.

**Sample data**

```
    ID     | Date           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | 03/10/2021     |
| 1        | 02/10/2021     |
| 2        | 03/10/2021     |
| 2        | 01/10/2021     |
| 2        | 00/00/0000     |
| 3        | 05/10/2021     |
| 3        | 01/10/2021     |
| 3        | 04/10/2021     |
| 3        | 00/00/0000     |
| 4        | 00/00/0000     |
| 5        | 05/02/2021     |
```

**Expected result**

```
    ID     | Min Date       |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | 02/10/2021     |
| 2        | 01/10/2021     |
| 3        | 01/10/2021     |
| 4        | 00/00/0000     |
| 5        | 05/02/2021     |
```

I currently have a simple

```
select d.id as ID
       min(d.date) as date
  from data d
 group by d.id
```

which obviously give me `00/00/0000` as the `min` date for e.g ID 2.

**Current result**

```
    ID     | Min Date       |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | 02/10/2021     |
| 2        | 00/00/2021     |
| 3        | 00/00/2021     |
| 4        | 00/00/0000     |
| 5        | 05/02/2021     |
```

**My approach**

I thought about using `having` and checking whether the date is greater than the default, but that'd eliminate the valid default entries as well, e.g for ID 4.

In pseudo-code, I'd need something like

```
select d.id,
       min( -- IF exist entry 'XY' where (d.date > default) then 'XY' else d.date) as date
  from 
 where data d
```

What's a correct solution for this?

Comment: show us your desired output as well

Comment: Is that a date type column or a string?

Comment: @CaiusJard - It can only be "string" - 00/00/0000 is not a valid date, so it can't be stored in a date type column.

Comment: You're making an assumption that the data as presented is a verbatim dump of what is stored in the table; I wasn't prepared to hence the question

Answer (score 1):

Use `nullif()`:

```
select d.id as ID
       min(nullif(d.date, '00/00/0000')) as date
from data d
group by d.id;
```

That returns the minimum of the date *as a string* because `'00/00/0000'` is not a valid *date*.  You should fix the data type and store appropriate values!

In the meantime, convert to a date:

```
select d.id as ID
       min(to_date(nullif(d.date, '00/00/0000'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')) as date
from data d
group by d.id;
```

This returns the value as a *date*.  Because `'00/00/0000'` is not a valid date, it is returned as `NULL`.  You can convert back to a string if you really need the values as strings.

Comment: This does almost what the OP needs. In the case the only "date" (or "dates") for an ID is 00/00/0000 then he still wants that returned, rather than NULL. Which also means that the output must be converted back to string...